# Frame to frame animation in UIKit project

Tags: ios, animation

I need to display frame to frame animation in my UIKit based project. I did not want to use Sprite Kit because my app is heavy based on UIKit elements where I have many scrollviews,textfield, pop out menu etc. Is there a way to display frame to frame images (like walking people or moving tree) but without involving in Sprite Kit? I am completely new to SpriteKit if I can avoid I do not want to involve in Sprite Kit.

Comment: Image view animation images https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationImages

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_uiimageview_and_uiimage_animation

Comment: yes you can easily do a frame animation animation using uikit ..

**animation like walking people,moving tries**, 

you can achive this by loading multiple images in a imageview and then play [imageview startanimating]; 

and then for moving an object from 1 place to another point , check out this answer
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895152/rotate-an-imageview-while-moving-it